# "Incompatible peer dependencies" error when updating from Angular v7.2 to v8

Tags: angular

I'm usually good about updating my project when a new version of Angular comes out and don't recall ever having any issues, but when trying to update from Angular v7.2.15 to v8.0.1 with `ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`, I get the following peer dependency errors:

[image]

I ran `ng update` and tried to update each package it listed individually. All of them gave me similar errors. I'm on Node v10.16.0 and NPM v6.9.0

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with the Angular packages, the issue is with the `codelyzer` package to a minimum version `5.0.0` which includes support for Angular v8.

Once you've updated that package, the `ng update` command you're using should work as you expect.